# Centrar un formulario de login con angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Con angular material, estoy intentando centrar un "mat-card" dentro de un "div". Intento centrarlo cambiando las propiedades de la clase de CSS "center-content", pero no puedo. Este es el código:

```css
.example-card {
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  .example-header-image {
    background-image: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .center-content {
      margin-top: 100px;
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      background-color: yellow;
  }
  .example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .example-full-width {
      margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mat-button{
      margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
  }
```

```html
<div class="center-content">
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <!-Aquí iría el contenido del matcard-->
    Contenido del mat-card
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Pero el mat-card class="example-card" no me sale centrado dento del DIV principal, me  sale echando a un lado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo el problema. El `mat-card` se muestra centrado.

Comment: Ok, quizá me expresé mal. Lo que quería conseguir es que el me salga el formulario en el centro de la página. No como ahora que sale a la izquierda completamente.

Comment: Sí, eso entendí. Pero probé el código que colocaste y el `mat-card` sale centrado por eso no veo el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto podrías usar las propiedades de flex con CSS, quedaría algo así:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.center-content{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Y tu HTML así:

```
<div class="center-content">
  <mat-card>
    <!-Aquí iría el contenido del matcard-->
    Contenido del mat-card
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Pues me sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Que extraño, estás agregando la propiedad height y width al HTML y body?

Comment: No. El html es la "vista" de un componente de angular. No he agregado nada de eso.

Comment: Agrega esto en el archivo style.css o scss de tu proyecto de angular: html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}